Getting html response insted of actual data on vercel hosted API
I'm working on a small React.js project with external newscather API. I deployed backend on vercel. Data is coming in properly and I can display when working in Locally with vercel hosted API (i.e backend;) but when I deploy frontend to vercel,an index.html file returns and giving message as:

You need to enable JavaScript to run this app

even though JavaScript is enabled manually.


I tried to resolve the issue by enabling and changing search engine but still get issue.
code snippets
[Api Fetching]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/wiHABq4Y.png

It's sending you an error page. Try to add some code for better understanding of how you're calling the API.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Sowmo0509  I Added Code snippets Can You please Check once again

Can you use Postman or Thunderbolt Client in VS Code to check the API endpoint? And where have you hosted your backend? How are you calling the backend from the frontend?

i am obeserved that the content-type get change , when i run the application locally and check via postman i get header Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8 . that i set but when i see on my hosted site it get change to "text/html; charset=utf-8" how to resolve this @Sowmo0509 and i hosted both frontend and backend on vercel frontend :-info-vista-61yq.vercel.app/Home
